# In RX how to combine two sources of different types

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

**Set up:**

- First `IObservable` produces values of type *A*
- Second `IObservable` produces values of type *B*
- They produce value at different pace (quite fast, up to every 10 ms)

**What I am trying to achieve:**

Every *N* time (N is quite slow about 500 ms) the call has to be done to the service and provide latest values from both *First* and *Second* `IObservable`.

**Question:**
I wonder how could I do using RX.

**Current solution (Non working)**:

```
var stateObs = from drag in dragObs.MostRecent(0).ToObservable()
                from roll in rollObs.MostRecent(0).ToObservable()
                select new ClientState
                            {
                                FileDragPerc = drag,
                                PhoneRoll = roll,
                                PendingFileType = FileType.Image,
                                TransferState = TransferState.SelectiveTransfer
                            };

stateObs.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
        .Subscribe(x => _lsService.SetClientStateAsync(x),
                    x => Debug.WriteLine("Error in observable "),
                    () => Debug.WriteLine("Error observable finished! "));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. That's what the `CombineLatest` operator does:

```
A: 1...2...3...4...5...

B: a.....b.........c...
```

The last value of either sequence is retained to generate a pair on which a selector acts. The output stream will be `(1,a) (2,a) (2,b) (3,b)` and so on.

If you have to construct proper pairs from either stream, use the 'Zip' operator, which will give you `(1,a) (2,b) (3,c)` and so on.

P.S.

I would suggest trying to get a better understanding of how the compiler rewrites query comprehensions. It will resolve most of your confusion.

```
from a in oA
from b in oB
select ...
```

is effectively `SelectMany(oA, oB)`

Comment: Yeap, problem with Zip is that because one source is of faster producing speed and if Zipped one will behind the other.

Comment: @Vitalij I would advise against using query comprehension syntax for Rx. Most of the operators are unavailable and you'll end up combining it with method operators and the whole thing will be a mess to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer myself

CombineLatest() operation does what I just need,
So that's what I get:

```
var stateObs = dragObs.CombineLatest(rollObs, (d, r) => new ClientState
                                                       {
                                                           FileDragPerc = d,
                                                           PhoneRoll = r,
                                                           TransferState = TransferState.SelectiveTransfer,
                                                           PendingFileType = FileType.Image
                                                       });

    stateObs.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
            .Subscribe(x => _lsService.SetClientStateAsync(x),
                        x => Debug.WriteLine("Error in observable "),
                        () => Debug.WriteLine("Error observable finished! "));
```